# Encapsulated the Ajax calls into a class and works odd when I'm using it to upload files

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I've recently used lots of Ajax methods in one of my projects, since in every $.ajax call you have to write many of the same codes, like:

```
{
  type:'POST', // Default value is 'GET'
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    // Usually do some Page Loading Animation stuff here
  },
  error:function(){
    // Handling the Exceptions here
  }
}
```

So I've encapsulated the Ajax call into a class, called JAjax, like this :

```
(function ($) {

// More details, see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
var defaults = {
    data: {},
    url: '',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    isOverlay: true,
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    processData: true,
    overlayTarget: $(document.body),
    dealyClean: 500,
    f_before: function () {},
    f_done: function () { },
    f_always: function () { },
    f_fail: function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            // Handling the Exceptions
        }
    }
};

function JAjax(_options) {
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, _options);
    this.execute();
}

function createOverLayer(options) {
    // Create a page loading animation layer
}

JAjax.prototype = {
    execute: function () {

        var parent = this;

        var response = $.ajax({
            data: parent.options.data,
            url: parent.options.url,
            type: parent.options.type,
            dataType: parent.options.dataType,
            contentType: parent.options.contentType,
            async: parent.options.async,
            cache: parent.options.cache,
            processData: parent.options.processData,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                parent.options.f_before();
                if (parent.options.isOverlay) {
                    createOverLayer(parent.options);
                }
            }
        });

        response.done(parent.options.f_done);
        response.always(parent.options.f_always);
        response.fail(parent.options.f_fail);

    }
};

jQuery.extend({
    jajax: function (_options) {
        _options = _options || {};
        if (typeof _options === 'object') {
            return new JAjax(_options);
        }
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

For most Ajax requests (GET, POST), it works fine. But when I use it to upload some files, The file will successfully upload to the server and back to me a filename(string) as an execution result. But somehow, it doesn't trigger the f_done function, below is how I use it to upload the files:

```
var url = '/ajax_common_file_upload';
var file_data = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
    var file = _files[i];
    file_data.append('input_files[]', file);
}

$.jajax({
    url: url,
    data: file_data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    f_done: function (result) {
        // Never to be executed :-(
        alert('show me something, please!');
    }
});
```

I spend days to try to figure it out why it doesn't 'SHOW ME SOMETHING' but all failed, will be very appreciated that someone can help me out and explain why the f_done() method cannot be triggered when I use it to upload files.

Update:
I made some screenshots for both JAjax and original $.ajax on Request Headers and merge them together like below:
[image]

I used the same parameters to make the request for both JAjax and $.ajax, but I don't know why they have a different Accept value!

ANYONE?

Answer (score 0):

Still can not trigger the f_done() function!!! but since I can do the same thing at f_always(), I'm gonna skip this and moving on. I will keep this post open and always appreciate for any suggestions!